# newtx bijection is bĳection

Tags: ligatures, newtx

Feeding

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}%%% 2020/07/22 v1.628
\begin{document}
bijection
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` leads to a PDF document (here is the image of it,

[image: expected bijection]

) in which you cannot copy `bi` or `jection` separately with the PDF readers Evince or Okular. If you don't use NewTX, you can select and copy `bi` or `jection` separately as expected. It seems to me that the glyph `ĳ` is graphically used (though copying the whole word from the text layer using the two PDF viewers correctly yields two separate letters `ij` inside the word).

Similarly, feeding `pdflatex` with

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% 2021/04/29 v2.0v
\usepackage{newtx}% 2024/02/08 v1.738
\begin{document}
bijection
\end{document}
```

as of 2024-02-17 yields

[image: output as of TeX Live 2023 on 2024-02-17]

where you cannot select `bi` or `jection` separately in Evince or Okular. If you don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or NewTX, you can select and copy `bi` or `jection` separately as expected. Though copying the whole word from the text layer using Okular yields two separate letters `ij` inside the word, copying the whole word from the text layer using Evince yields the ligature `ĳ` inside the word. So it seems to me that the character or glyph `ĳ` is graphically used.

If this character or glyph `ĳ` is really used here, then it incorrectly spans the linguistical morpheme boundary; in any case you should be able to select and copy the “bi” part separately.  How to avoid this weird behavior?

More information: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142681

The NewTX maintainer has been informed.

Comment: @campa evince, okular

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior, both with Evince and Okular I can select `i` and `j` separately. I do have a slightly older version of `newtxtext` though (v1.531, 2018/03/27) so maybe it is different in the most recent version.

Comment: @Marijn Mine is newer: 2020/07/22 v1.628. I recall that with the old one, the bug did not occur.

Comment: it is not a bug, it is a ligature ;-). You can input `bi\/jection` to split it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thx! Is it possible to have it done automatically for all the occurrences of "bijection" in the text (other that defining a new command by means of something like `\def\bijection{bi\/jection}`)? Or perhaps, turning this ligature off completely?

Comment: ask the maintainer. Imho it is an rather odd choice to make this a ligature by default.

Comment: The T1 encoding has the glyphs “IJ” and “ij” but these should not be used for ligatures, because they're specific for Dutch. The font should instead define a kerning for the combination `i`+`j`. If I force OT1 encoding, the glyphs are indeed separate, but `newtxtext` uses T1 by default.

Comment: @egreg I should admit I cannot decypher the PDF to find out whether the Dutch glyph ĳ is really used (or whether it is some other glyph), but that's what it looks based on the behavior in the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### UPDATE

In version 1.631 (and some later versions, not including v1.71) of the NewTX fonts the issue is fixed.

#### Original answer

The current version of the text font `ntx-Regular-tlf-t1` has

```
   (LABEL C I)
   (LIG C J O 234)
   (STOP)
[...]
   (LABEL C i)
   (LIG C j O 274)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.03)
   (KRN C j R -0.035)
   (KRN C T R -0.03)
   (STOP)
```

Maybe the code above is cryptic, but it's what I get from `tftopl` that shows `tfm` files in (nearly) human readable form. The `LABEL C i` instruction introduces ligatures and kerning for the character at ASCII position for `i` as the first element.

Here `LIG C j O 274` tells TeX that `i` followed by `j` should be replaced with the glyph sitting at slot octal 274 (in T1 encoding it's indeed the composite “ij” for Dutch). Instead `KRN C T R -0.03` tells TeX that between `i` and `T` there should be a negative kern amounting to 3/100 of the design size (but this will be scaled by the magnification factor the font is loaded at). There is a `KRN C j R -0.035` instruction, but since `LIG C j` comes first, the latter is discarded.

In previous versions of `newtxtext` fonts there is no ligature map for `I` and for `i` we read

```
   (LABEL C i)
   (KRN C j R -0.035)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.03)
   (KRN C T R -0.03)
   (STOP)
```

Adding the ligatures `I`+`J` mapping to the character at octal 234 and `i`+`j` mapping to octal 274 is wrong.

The T1 encoding has indeed glyphs “IJ” and “ij” at those positions, but they're specific for the Dutch language and its capitalization rules. They should not be used as general ligatures. This oversight has to be fixed by the maintainer.

In the meantime, you can use `microtype` to disable the wrong ligatures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}%%% 2020/07/22 v1.628
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[I,i]{encoding=T1}

\begin{document}

bijection

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the kern is still applied. Disabling the ligature resurrects the kern mentioned above.

Comment: Thx! (1) Are there any other ligatures besides `ĳ` that `\DisableLigatures[I,i]{encoding=T1}` would disable? (2) Is it possible to restrict `\DisableLigatures[I,i]{encoding=T1}` to all languages except Dutch (e.g., when you use `\usepackage[USenglish,british,dutch,latin,german,ngerman]{babel}`)?

Comment: @GeekestGeek No, there is no provision for enabling ligatures only for a particular language. This might be possible with OpenType fonts. From the ligature tables I showed, there is no other ligature involving `i` as the first element.

Comment: It would be nice to have such a provision, which would allow us to quote a paper of `Dĳkstra` in Dutch and to talk about `bijections` in English :-).  As for now, the most reasonable way seems to forbid such a ligature as you stated (or go with selnolig+LuaLaTex as Mico said).

Comment: Let me just add that `ij` is one of the most common combinations in Slavic languages.  It is almost impossible for `a` to follow `i` directly, so `j` is put in between by the rule.

Answer (score 3):

If you're free to employ LuaLaTeX to compile your document, you can employ the [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package to suppress the `ij` ligature automatically if the `newtxtext` text font package is in use.

[image]

If you compare the first and second word in each row, you'll notice that the kern between `i` and `j` is not affected by the operation of the selnolig package, even as the ligature is no longer there.

AFAICT, there are no good uses of the `ij`-ligature in English-language documents, even for words which have a Latin root -- e.g., `bijection` -- or which derive from another modern language, e.g., `bijou`, `jipijapa` (aka Panama hat), and `Marijuana` (Maryjane -- what else could you possibly have in mind?).

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} % is required by 'selnolig'
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{selnolig}

\begin{document}
bijection bi\kern0ptjection

\em bijection bi\kern0ptjection
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use LuaTeX, you would mostly like to employ OpenType fonts (rather than T1 fonts) anyway, wouldn't you?

Comment: @GeekestGeek - Definitely. The main points of the answer are (a) that LuaLaTeX can be used just fine with the `newtxtext` package and (b) that such a setup allows use of the selnolig package even if no OpenType font is used. Aside: Not many OpenType fonts offer an `ij` ligature. One of the few that does (and that I'm aware of) is the italic face of `Garamond Premier Pro`.

Comment: TeX Gyre Termes version 2.004 offers the `ĳ` ligature, too. But IMHO it's visually indistinguishable from a properly kerned `ij`.