# Issues with unwanted ij ligature in NewTX

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, ligatures, newtx

The issue in [newtx bijection is bĳection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569282/newtx-bijection-is-b%c4%b3ection) has re-emerged.  Namely, compiling

```
\documentclass{standalone}% 2018/03/26 v1.3a
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% 2021/04/29 v2.0v
\usepackage[dutch,ngerman,USenglish]{babel}% 2022/05/22 3.75
\usepackage{newtxtext}% 2022/02/28 v1.71
\begin{document}
bijection
\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Bijektion}
\foreignlanguage{dutch}{Dijkstra}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` (version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 from TeX Live 2022/Debian; package version numbers are given in the comments above) yields

[image: output]

, in which you cannot copy `Bi`, `jektion`, `bi`, `jection`, `Di`, and `jkstra` separately with the PDF readers Evince or Okular.
If you don't use fontenc or NewTX, you can select and copy all the parts separately as expected. It seems to me that the glyph `ĳ` is graphically used (though copying any of the three words from the text layer using Okular correctly yields two separate letters `ij` inside the word). If the glyph `ĳ` is really used here, then it incorrectly spans the linguistical morpheme boundary; in any case you should be able to select and copy the “bi” and “Bi” part separately.

Though the usage of a ligature seems to be a matter of taste in Dutch for Dijkstra/Dĳkstra (cf. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142682/typesetting-in-dutch-dijkstra-vs-d%c4%b3kstra), it is plainly wrong for the German *Bijektion* and the English *bijection*.

Why has this weird behavior re-emerged? Any new recipes to avoid it or the same as in 2020?

This question is specific to pdflatex (for {lua|xe}latex we do something else anyway).

I have informed the NewTX maintainer. (However, I received no reply to my prior messages from two months ago, so whoever wishes to ping him, please feel free…)

PS. Dutch *vrijgeven* seems to get typeset using a ligature now, too, and I don't know whether it is acceptable.  French *Dijon* (a city) also seems to get typeset using a ligature; this is clearly wrong.

Comment: ligatures in tfm fonts are font specified so not controllable by babel or other language macros unless you have multiple versions of the font metrics with and without the ligature.

Comment: you can use `i\/j` to prevent ligatures, or simpler use microtype as in egreg's answer to the linked question

Comment: No issues when compiling with LuaLaTeX, either.

Comment: Your last sentence ending "this is clearly wrong" isn't clearly true, it assumes some semantic meaning is associated to the ligature rather than a purely visual adjustment of the typsetting to avoid clash of serifs, or to adjust the character width to help with justification. Both views are possible although the classic tfm version of ligaturing is closer to the latter as it is part of the font metric and can not be changed at point of use. "Dijon (a city) also seems to get typeset using a ligature;"  is a consequence of "every ij pair is ligatured". The word or language are not considered.

Comment: I guess that some script is responsible for the issue. Inform the package maintainer that the problem was fixed in 2020, but already reappeared in 2021

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got you. The absence of dependency on the language and on the word itself is, as we see, unfortunate; this has to be improved. There is no clash of letters in the upright font either way. There is a simplicity argument: a ligature in the aforementioned cases is pointless in three languages (German, English, French) and MIGHT be useful, in the opinion of some folks, in one (Dutch), to represent a Dutch digraph. And, of course, the ligature confuses the PDF viewers: there is no good reason for why i and j should be not selectable separately in German, English, and French words.

Comment: the ligaturing mechanism is unlikely to change in pdftxex, and as seen, if you use opentype and luatex/xetex it isn't a issue. Of course as egreg hinted the ij ligature here may have been added by mistake and may go, I was more addressing the general issue that you don't need to test different words, if one ij ligatures, all ij in that font will ligature if done by classic tex. (cut and paste selection could be fixed just as ff ligatures paste as two f, would just need a suitable unicode mapping being supplied (I think)

Comment: @Ingmar Before having edited the title, had you seen the actual differences in the words mentioned there?

Comment: I have. I just didn't think that spelling out bĳection, Bĳektion and Dijkstra in the title was necessary or, in fact, helpful. Feel free to change the title again if you think this describes your issue inadequately.

Comment: @egreg Though I informed the NewTX maintainer on this matter now, I have to say that I received no reply to my prior e-mails to him on a different matter from two months ago. If you or anyone else wish to ping him, please feel free…

Comment: As of today, this issue seems to be repaired in the current TeX Live 2023 with newtxtext v1.723. So whoever feels responsible, please feel free to confirm/deny this and, if necessary, supply an answer to the question or simply close it.

Comment: The symbol ĳ would only make sense as a ligature when the two glyphs i and j graphically clash when simply juxtaposed. However, in typical English or German typography, they NEVER clash. IMHO, they may (but need not) clash only in certain fancy typesettings of Dutch. So the combination of the term “ligature” in Unicode's name of U+0133 with the fact that tons of fonts simply juxtapose the two plain symbols i and j into a single plain non-clashing ĳ looks strange to me.